# Sass как разместить :not :hover, чтобы заработало

Tags: sass

```
    &:hover:not(.social-links)
        background-color: black
        color: white
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 &:not(.social-links):hover
    background-color: black
    color: white
```

Вам же нужно сделать hover если класс элемента не .social-links

Поэтому мы исключаем .social-links

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]